# Event when textbox receive date from Calendar Extender

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How to have a event when date is selected from Calendar Extender and it does a function in aspx.cs

```
   Filter by Date:<asp:TextBox ID="txtDatePicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
           Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDatePicker" />
```

Comment: You could use this library i developed is much flexiable :)
https://github.com/AlenToma/FancyDatePicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute a JavaScript function when a date is selected then subscribe to `onchange` event of the textbox attached to CalendarExtender. This is an event on client-side and not server-side.

You can use the snippet below to call a function `doSomething()` when a date is selected. Note the `onchange` attribute I have added to markup for textbox.

```
 Filter by Date:<asp:TextBox ID="txtDatePicker" runat="server" onchange="doSomething()"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
           Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDatePicker" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
        function doSomething() {
            var x = 100;
            alert(x);
        }
    </script>
```